# why g-hub lua mouse move operations doesn't work in League of Legends?

Tags: lua, logitech

**my code like this ,anything about mousemove doesn't work in the game ,but keyboard operation work correctly in the game ,why?**

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
        x, y = GetMousePosition();
        OutputLogMessage("Mouse is at %d, %d\n", x, y);
        middle = 32767
        MoveMouseTo(middle, middle)
        PressKey("e")
        Sleep(100)
        ReleaseKey("e")
        Sleep(500)
        a = 5000
        sina = x / math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)
        cosa = y / math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)
        OutputLogMessage("sina: %f, cosa: %f\n", sina, cosa)
        new_x = sina * a
        new_y = cosa * a
        OutputLogMessage("new_x: %f, new_y: %f\n", new_x, new_y)
        next_ex = middle + new_x
        next_ey = middle + new_y
        OutputLogMessage("next_ex: %f, next_ey: %f\n", next_ex, next_ey)
        MoveMouseTo(math.ceil(next_ex), math.ceil(next_ey))
        Sleep(100)
        m, n = GetMousePosition();
        OutputLogMessage("Mouse is at %d, %d\n", m, n);
        Sleep(100)
        MoveMouseRelative( -100, -100)
    end

end
```

Comment: Open the GHUB script editor and look at the error message in the bottom output window.  What does it say? (You should copy this code to default profile for testing)

Comment: no error log out in console,  in desktop it work correctly , in game only keyboard operation work ,mousemove code doesn't work ,you can try it in league and legends, both of them out same log

Comment: Do you see all `OutputLogMessage` output correctly printed?

Comment: yes , all log output correctly, moveposition  log print , it stay at same place

Answer (score 0):

Some games (including League of Legends) ignore user input which is too fast to be human.
For example, human is unable to move the mouse immediately across the entire screen, so such mouse movement is ignored.
You should simulate human-like behavior: mouse speed should not exceed 10 pixels per millisecond, time between key press and release should be more than 20ms, and so on.

So, use `MoveMouseRelative` in a loop instead of `MoveMouseTo`

Comment: `function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5) then
        x, y = GetMousePosition();
        OutputLogMessage("Mouse is at %d, %d\n", x, y);
        Sleep(50)
        MoveMouseRelative(10, 10)
        Sleep(50)
        MoveMouseRelative(10, 10)
        m, n = GetMousePosition();
        OutputLogMessage("Mouse is at %d, %d\n", m, n);
    end
end`
 it alse useless in game

Comment:  how to make it work

Comment: Implement your own `MoveMouseToSlowly` which moves slowly until mouse reaches the target point.  And use it instead of `MoveMouseTo` in your original script.